# Windows 8.1 - Screen-off and Brightness

Tags: display, windows-8.1, brightness

When the Screen switches off after the timer, and then switched back on by moving the mouse, the screen's brightness changes to 2-3 Brightness key presses above what it used to be. So if it was set on 30% before screen switched off, upon switching on, it would be 50-60% brightness. I have to constantly turn it down every time this happens.

I am using Dell Studio 1558, Windows 8.1 Professional.

Any ideas what's wrong?

**Edit:** This problem did not happen in Windows 8, only after 8.1 update

Comment: Have you (re)installed all the utilities for your notebook from Dell?  Specifically with Windows 8.1-ready versions?

Comment: unfortunately, my laptop came with windows 7 when I bought it 3 years ago, and this model comes only in Windows 7. Therefore Dell do not have any windows 8.1 utilities for my model, I searched Dell software and drivers with my laptop tag as well as a general search for this model. Nothing windows 8 related comes up.

Comment: You may be out of luck then, since they don't support that OS on that notebook. :(  Maybe someone else has found a way though.. good luck! :)

Comment: Try turning off the auto-brightness feature in the 8.1 settings.

Comment: I have, it has no effect for some reason.